# 'Year' variable not applied in Earth Engine Example?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I wonder if the year variable in Google Earth Engine's example 'Sentinel2 Clear Composites' is actually applied or working. https://code.earthengine.google.com/1885668f9f476d9f8f917b2fde0b00cd

To the best of my knowledge, all the Sentinel2-Images with the set month are used in this example but correct me, if i'm wrong.

How would you implement the year variable?

Answer (score 1):

No, that variable isn't used.  It's leftover from previous versions of the code.  The collection should include a filterDate() to subset down to just the 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

To filter for a specific year, on the same line as the months filter, you just need to add another filter which also uses the .calendarRange() method like this:
`return linkedCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year,year,'year'))`

Here is the link to the snapshot of the whole code you would run - I have also added a couple more of lines of code to add year to image properties as well as layer names.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e12a84bbc48bf7dd859b5744b4121ad9